# HTML Popup Div to center of screen of any screen resolution

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

I have following html div:

```
<div id="AddUser" style="background-color: White; border: 2px solid black; display: none;
        width: 800px; z-index: 1001; top: 60px; left: 240px; position: fixed; padding-left: 10px">
        <table width="98%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" align="center">
                   -------Content-----
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I am showing this div as a popup by `style.display='block`

But its appearing at different places at different screen resolutions.

I wanted to get it in the center of screen for any screen resolution.

Hence i given `left` and `top` as a %

But then also it didnot viewd correctly.

What can be solution to this problem???

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here I made a JSfiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/P3pe8/2/)

Here is your CSS

```
#AddUser{
 display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
width: 800px;
min-height: 800px;
padding: 25px;
 border: 2px solid black; 



}
#parent
{
position:absolute;
border: 2px solid red; 
left:0px;
top:0px;
right:0px;
bottom:0px;
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 40px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

And here is your html:

```
<div id="parent">

<div id="AddUser" >
    <table >
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6" align="center">
               -------Content-----
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This always centers perfectly no matter how large the screen or the content of the AddUser div.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate screen width and overlay width, and use calculated left as below:

```
var left = (screenWidth - OverlayWidth) / 2
```

this will keep you div centrally aligned every time.

Ex:

```
  var screenWidth = $(window).width(),
      overlayWidth = $('#AddUser').width(),
      calculatedLeft = (screenWidth - overlayWidth) / 2;

  $('#AddUser').css({
     left: calculatedLeft,
     position: fixed
  });

//without using jQuery

   var screenWidth = window.screen.width,
       overlay = document.getElementById('AddUser'),
       overlayWidth = overlay.width,
       calculatedLeft = (screenWidth - overlayWidth) / 2;

overlay.style.left = calculatedLeft + "px";
```

Comment: where should i write this?

Comment: will this be get applied without jQuery also?

Comment: yeah same logic you can write in core javascript.